# Should I refer to the implementation while writing unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing

I was assigned a task regarding writing unit tests for some already-implemented classes.

Currently I am not really understand the purposes of each class. My concern is that whether I should (1) deeply dive into implementation, or (2) just simply see input - expected output of each class (as well as its methods)?

IMO:

(1) has an advantage that I can see some potential bugs so that I can design unit tests that can cover those cases.

In the other hand, (1) has disadvantages that are (a) I can get biased by the implementation and (b): takes time.

Comment: If you have no idea what the purposes of the classes are, how could you possibly write tests for them? The writer of a class should be the one writing the tests for it.

Comment: In fact is quite the opposite. The writer of the implementation tends to test **that current implementation** instead of testing the specification so is quite recommendable that different people write tests and implementation. And if tests are written before implementation is even better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you do **both**.

First, and foremost, you focus on the **public contract** of the classes under test. So yes, looking at input/output should be your "first stop".

You see - ideally, your unit test do not need any kind of mocking. You create some instance `underTest`; you call a method; you observe/verify some behavior (for example asserting an expected against the actual return value).

But of course, sometimes it is **worth** looking into the details of the implementation.

So, a reasonable procedure is:

- write "black box" tests that don't know about implementation details (where possible)
- use coverage to understand how "good" your tests are covering the class under test

From the coverage numbers you can draw further conclusions, like:

- your black box tests aren't sufficient, and you need to add certain "white box" tests in order to get into specific methods. Meaning: you look into the class under test to understand what it is doing; and how to get into important corners.
- your tests are actually great - but there is unused code in those classes under test. Maybe that can then be deleted (deleting source code is the second best thing you can do as software engineer!)

Finally: it is more of an **anti pattern** to create unit tests that (more or less) re-program the implementation. You really want to avoid that your unit tests do nothing else but configure mocks for those calls that your production code is making. Thing is: when you test *implementation details*, then any implementation change (like a simple refactoring/reordering) can break your unit tests.

Comment: Don't know if you checked this one or not but 2 of your sentences contradict each other: "ideally, your unit test do not need any kind of mocking" and "You really want to avoid that your unit tests do nothing else but configure mocks for those calls that your production code is making"

Comment: @Farid I don't see a contradiction. A) you try to avoid mocks (base rule) B) when you use mocks, then avoid those tests that are "line by line" repeating your production code in terms of mock setup.